# Using EclipseLink JPA in WAR in WSO2 Application Server

Tags: java, jpa, wso2, eclipselink, wso2-as

I have an existing WAR, containing JAX-WS services, using EclipseLink JPA to connect with an Oracle database. I want to deploy this on the WSO2 Application Server.

Since WSO2AS comes with Hibernate, the way to get this to work seems to be to include the necessary EclipseLink jars in the WAR.
I included these jars in WEB-INF/lib:

- org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.2.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.2.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.2.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.5.2.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.5.2.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.oracle-2.5.2.jar

When I deploy the war by copying it to wso2as-5.3.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps, I get this error message:

```
[2016-09-30 12:09:46,761] ERROR {org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder} -  Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hello]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/koert/software/wso2as-5.3.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/hello: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [pasPU] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/JMXServerPlatformBase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [pasPU] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/JMXServerPlatformBase
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:970)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:652)
...
```

The JMXServerPlatformBase class is contained in org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.2.jar, so this looks like a classloading problem.

I tried to put the EclipseLink jars in:
- lib/runtimes/ext
- repository/components/lib

After that, I still get the same exception.

I have a webapp-classloading.xml in META-INF with Javaee in Environments.

How can I get EclipseLink working in WSO2AS?

Comment: Are those EclipseLink jars OSGi Bundles? As far as I know WSO2 Servers are OSGi Servers.

Comment: No, the EclipseLink jars I have used look like ordinary jars. I grabbed them from the Maven repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.5.0